# Can TableRowSorter be used to do background sorting or backend sorting?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sorting, tablerowsorter

There is a usability issue when you have a `JTable` with a huge number of rows in conjunction with the normal `TableRowSorter`. Sorting on any column will fetch all the values for that column. This is all done on the EDT, which freezes the application for potentially a very long time. It's doubly-bad because it also does the sorting on the EDT even though it doesn't have to.

So I'm wondering whether there is a right way to do this.

I already have a thread-safe `TableModel` which is safe to call on a background thread. Is there an elegant way to have it fetch the values on another thread instead of doing it on the EDT?

But really, eventually I would like to do the sort at the backend, so perhaps there is an elegant way to hook the table's row sorter up to changing the actual query being used to fetch the data? It's something that I thought was being worked on in some jdesktop project in the past, but I don't think I ever saw what came from that.

In both these situations, there is an associated usability issue of indicating that a sort has been specified but hasn't completed yet, which I'm not entirely sure the `JTable` look and feel will display, but who knows, maybe it will.

Comment: Your `TableModel` might be thread safe, but `JTable` isn't, so becareful there. The basic idea would be to offload the sorting to another thread (obviously), but you're going to have to do all this work yourself, as `TableRowSorter` isn't designed to work this way (AFAIK). One of the features of sorter API is doesn't sort the physical data, so the model remains unchanged, so you'll need to decide if this is what you want or not. You could sort the underlying data and do a single batch update to the UI, which might be more efficient the multiple small updates

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have a wrapping TableModel which I put in the table itself so that all the updates to the table do still occur on the EDT. I also have a ThreadCheckingRepaintManager which would loudly complain if anything were done on the wrong thread, so I know that nothing is misbehaving. :)

Comment: Or you could use a proxy model, which does a virtual sort (like the sorter API), but does it's work in a background thread (like `SwingWorker`), but which preserves the original model (this is how we did things before the sorting API)